# Changing two select elements based on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two HTML selects elements:

```
<select name="businessName">
    <option name="d3"> Car Ltd </option>
    <option name="e11"> Food Business </option>
    <option name="f2"> Builders </option>
</select>

<select name="businessCode">
    <option name="d3"> d3 </option>
    <option name="e11"> e11 </option>
    <option name="f2"> f2 </option>
</select>
```

How would I use JavaScript/jQuery so when I change one select, the other one will change? E.g.:

- so when i choose Car LTD, it will show d3
- or when i choose Builders it will show f2
- or when i choose f2 it will show Builders in the other

Comment: If the two selects' values must always match anyways, are two separate `<select>` elements even necessary? Why not just change the text to something like `<option>Car Ltd - d3</option>`, or is there something specific you're trying to do by having two `<select>` elements?

Comment: In general, stackoverflow is for questions when you get stuck having already tried to write code, not questions which are basically: write this code for me which I have not even tried to write myself. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the posted question if the OP had value instead of name then the question would have been very simple. But a name or any other custom attribute makes the selection a bit complex. As a matter of fact most of the answers posted do not address what is actually asked.I agree that the OP should have searched similar questions first.

Answer (score 3):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wivelu/2/edit?html,js,output)***

Altually your `options` should have a **VALUE** attribute (instad of `name`):

```
<select name="businessName">
    <option value="d3"> Car Ltd </option>
    <option value="e11"> Food Business </option>
    <option value="f2"> Builders </option>
</select>

<select name="businessCode">
    <option value="d3"> d3 </option>
    <option value="e11"> e11 </option>
    <option value="f2"> f2 </option>
</select>
```

than this is all you need:

```
var $sel = $('[name=businessName], [name=businessCode]');

$sel.change(function(){
  $sel.not(this).val( this.value );
});
```

Comment: actually.. this may be the worst way to do this.. after the user's initial value change, it would raise the change event on the select control, reassign the new value to the same select control and change the value of the second select control .. which would raise this event again. reassigning the values again to both select controls (but not firing of the change event because it's not  'changing' them). .. you would end up assigning the new value to the initial select control 3 times, and 2 times to the other control.

Comment: I was wrong any, "Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using .val() for example, won't fire the event." http://api.jquery.com/change/ .. at most, it would have been 1 reassignment.. to that point adding `$sel.not(this).change();` may be appropriate in some implementations..

Comment: @BrettCaswell are you telling me that I should stop listening to suggestions and just follow my instinct? ;)

Comment: haha.. no. sorry for the confusion.. your version `$sel.not(sender).val()` was correct.  In my previous comment, I was referring to a seperate concern with regards to using events on multiselectors, and implementations using `val()`. I put together a (console.log) sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qtuq8rk2/1/

Comment: and this is the solution to that consideration (more or less): http://jsfiddle.net/qtuq8rk2/2/

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
var $businessNameSelect = $('[name=businessName]');
var $businessCodeSelect = $('[name=businessCode]');
$businessNameSelect.on('change', function() {
  $businessCodeSelect[0].selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
$businessCodeSelect.on('change', function() {
  $businessNameSelect[0].selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/md7cf69s/). The key is operating on `selectedIndex` property of `HTMLSelectElement`. Quoting [DOM Level 2 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-85676760):

> `selectedIndex` of **type** long
>
> The ordinal index of the selected option, starting from 0. The value
>   -1 is returned if no element is selected.

Answer (score 1):

### Sample Code Snippet

```js
    $("#bsname").change(function() {
        $("#bscode")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    });

    $("#bscode").change(function() {
        $("#bsname")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="bsname" name="businessName">
        <option name="d3"> Car Ltd </option>
        <option name="e11"> Food Business </option>
        <option name="f2"> Builders </option>
    </select>

    <select id="bscode" name="businessCode">
       <option name="d3"> d3 </option>
       <option name="e11"> e11 </option>
       <option name="f2"> f2 </option>
    </select>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnwd7Lv/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what is actually expected:

```js
$(".dittoSelect").change(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("name") == "businessName") {
    
    $("#businessCode option[name='" + $('option:selected', this).attr('name') + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
    
  } else {
    
    $("#businessName option[name='" + $('option:selected', this).attr('name') + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="businessName" id="businessName" class="dittoSelect">
  <option name="d3">Car Ltd</option>
  <option name="e11">Food Business</option>
  <option name="f2">Builders</option>
</select>

<select name="businessCode" id="businessCode" class="dittoSelect">
  <option name="d3">d3</option>
  <option name="e11">e11</option>
  <option name="f2">f2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("id") == this.id`

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few jQuery methods and thought it would be a good idea to offer a different method that doesn't require jQuery.

```js
    function Events(){
       var selections = document.getElementsByClassName('selection');
       // Add EventListeners to each element with the class off Selection
        for(var i=0; i<selections.length; i++) {
         selections[i].addEventListener("change",function(){PreSelect(this)},false);
        }
    }
    function PreSelect(e){
     var selections = document.getElementsByClassName('selection');
     for(var i=0; i<selections.length; i++) {
      //Set select to changed index
         selections[i].selectedIndex=e.selectedIndex;
        }
    }
    window.onload=Events;
```

```html
    <select class="selection" name="businessName">
        <option name="d3"> Car Ltd </option>
        <option name="e11"> Food Business </option>
        <option name="f2"> Builders </option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="selection" name="businessCode">
       <option name="d3"> d3 </option>
       <option name="e11"> e11 </option>
       <option name="f2"> f2 </option>
    </select>
```